# PHP-FPM with Apache 2.2.22 and Ubuntu 12.10 - 500 Error, or returns text (not executing)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, php-fpm

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.failover.co/blog/quick-setup-apache-worker-fastcgi-php-fpm-and-apc) to try to install PHP-FPM on my LAMP stack.

My config in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` contains (as per the guide)

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        Alias /php5.fastcgi /var/www/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi
        AddHandler php-script .php
        FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi -socket /var/run/php-fpm.sock
        Action php-script /php5.fastcgi virtual

# This part is not necessary to get it to work, but it stops anything else from being
# accessed from it by mistake or maliciously.
        <Directory "/var/www/fastcgi">
                Order allow,deny
                <Files "php5.fastcgi">
                        Order deny,allow
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Which resulted in 500 errors. I checked the Apache log and am seeing:

> (111)Connection refused: FastCGI: failed to connect to server
>   "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi": connect() failed FastCGIExternalServer
>   /var/www/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi -socket /var/run/php-fpm.sock
>   FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"

I checked and realised my `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` was listening on a different socket location (from the tutorial), so I updated the apache config to:

`FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

But now visiting a php5 script just shows plain text.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here, can anyone point me in the right direction to troubleshooting this? Unfortunately everything I've found is very NGINX oriented (or the user just switched to NGINX entirely!) I am somewhat tied to Apache at the moment as I am relying on .htaccess for wordpress and permalink rewrites etc.

Endless thanks in advance.

Comment: you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Ricalsin Unfortunately not, it would be incredibly useful if I could as well... at the moment I have to do all sorts of crazy permissions to have things running properly while still being able to edit files from my own user account

Answer (score 1):

Try using the parameters -idle-timeout and -appConnTimeout in the FastCgiExternalServer in the httpd.conf. Check this out [for the syntax](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?3,235805,235844)

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps... I had systematic 500 Internal Errors and had to struggle a lot to make **php-fpm** work with **Apache** and **IPSCONFIG** on a **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty**, build with [Falko tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3)

This is my working PHP-FPM configuration:

- /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

  ```
  user = www-data
  group = www-data
  listen.owner = www-data
  listen.group = www-data
  listen.mode = 0660
  listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
  pm = dynamic
  pm.max_children = 10
  pm.start_servers = 4
  pm.min_spare_servers = 2
  pm.max_spare_servers = 6
  pm.max_requests = 2000
  pm.status_path = /fpm_status?full
  chdir = /
  ```
- /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf

  ```
  pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
  error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
  include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
  ```
- /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php-fpm.conf

  ```
  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    Alias /php-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5
    AddHandler php .php
    Action php /php-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>
  ```
- I had to `chmod 666 /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`
- Last, but this is **specific to Ispconfig**, when I set a website with PHP-FPM into IspConfig, it writes the following lines in its sites-enabled vhost :

  ```
  Alias /php5-fcgi ALIAS_PATH&NAME
  FastCgiExternalServer ALIAS_PATH&NAME -idle-timeout 300 -host 127.0.0.1:9016 -pass-header Authorization</code>
  ```

  I have to change `-host 127.0.0.1:9016` to `-socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`, then it works.

Just don't know where IspConfig takes the wrong information from.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue, on Ispconfig with ubuntu 14.XX, Apache and PHP-FPM usign just this:

```
chmod 666 /var/lib/php5-fpm/web104.sock
```

Where web104 is the instance for the hosting 'web104'.

Hope this helps!